# Jmeter conditionally run iteration upon test resutls

Tags: java, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to create a test plan that will run multiple iterations of stress test.
The idea I'm trying to implement is to run 1 minute of HTTP requests to the server and maintain a constant throughput.
Then increase the desired throughput and run the test again for 1 minute.
I would like to increase the throughput by 100 Requests per Second on each iteration until I see that the actual throughput is much lower than the desired one.

I have successfully created a test plan that runs a constant throughput for a minute:
I have a thread group with X threads, and I set the scheduler to duration of 60 seconds.
In that thread group I have an HTTP Request Sampler and a Constant Throughput Timer which I set to a desired value.

However I would like to run that in a loop and increase the desired value in the Constant Throughput Timer on each iteration.

Also I would like to stop the loop (Or skip consecutive iteration ) when I see that the actual throughput as observed in Aggregate Report is much lower than the throughput I set in the Constant Throughput Timer for that iteration.

So basically when I reach the point that my server cannot keep up, I don't want to keep stressing it more.

How could I achieve the above described functionalities?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- To increase the throughput by 100 each iteration

  - define it as a property in the Constant Throughput Timer using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) like `${__P(throughput)}`
  - define `throughput` property initial value in [*user.properties* file or via -J command-line argument](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) (you can even do it outside JMeter using [Beanshell server feature](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server))
  - add [Test Action](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Action) sampler to the end of your Thread Group (it doesn't generate any sample result so it won't appear in the logs)
  - add [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the Test Action sampler and put the following code into "Script" area:

    ```
    def throughput = Integer.parseInt(props.get('throughput'))
    throughput += 6000
    props.put('throughput', String.valueOf(throughput))
    ```

  This way each iteration throughput will be increased by 6000 requests per minute (100 requests per second)
- You can use [AutoStop Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) in order to stop overwhelming your server basing on various criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I see though that the AutoStop Listener can only access average response time, average latency and error rate. But I would like to stop when the actual throughput as shown in the Aggregate Listener is much lower than the desired.

Comment: Also would you mind sharing an example? I've followed everything you mentioned, and I'm not getting the expected result.